# How to create an angular filter that outputs a unique ID

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-digest

The question is quite simple, How can you create an angularJs filter that will concatenate any input to a unique ID. This can be very useful for generating HTML id's, or to define unique attribute values for a group of elements in a ng-repeat.

**NOTE: The ID must be 'globally' unique which makes angular ng-repeat's `$index` useless.**

Now, the solution that probably comes to your mind is something like this:

`myModule.filter('uniqueId', function(){
    var idCounter = 0;
    return function(input) {
        return (input || '') + (++idCounter);
    };
});`

and in your HTML you write something like:

`<div id="{{groupName | uniqueId}}">`

The challenge is that angular will run into a digest loop, because evaluating `groupName | uniqueId` will never yield the same value which means the scope will never settle.

One last thing. We use angular v1.2.27 which means we can't use angular 1.3's new `::` (i.e. one time binding) operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can bind to an object instead of an individual property you could do something like the following:

check the object for the unique value. if present return it. if not present generate one, assign it and return it.

```
myModule.filter('uniqueId', function(){
    var idCounter = 0;
    return function(input) {
        return input.$$uniqueValue || (input.$$uniqueValue = ++idCounter);
    };
});
```

Not sure if this exactly fixes you problem but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks David, this definitely solves the problem in some cases. However, using an object means you can't concatenate the uniqueId to an existing input string (HTML id's must start with [A-Za-z]), or you must do something like: `return input.$$uniqueValue || (input.$$uniqueValue = (input.$$groupName || '') + ++idCounter)`